# On the quantity of twin prime pairs of a given form

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-constellations

Let $p_l$ the $l$-th prime number.  I've considered the formula

$$\frac{N_{n+1}}{N_n}+\frac{N_{n+2}}{p_{n+1}N_n}\pm1$$
where $N_k=\prod_{l=1}^k p_l$ is the primorial of order $k$. Previous formula can be simplified thus as $$p_{n+1}+p_{n+2}\pm 1.\tag{1}$$

I wondered, for $n\geq 1$ running over positive integers, when the terms of previous sequence provide us twin prime pairs $$(p_{n+1}+p_{n+2}-1, p_{n+1}+p_{n+2}+1).\tag{2}$$

> **Question.** Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime number. Is it possible to prove that there exist finitely many twin prime pairs of the form $$(p_{n+1}+p_{n+2}-1, p_{n+1}+p_{n+2}+1)$$ when $n$ runs over positive integers ? **Many thanks.**

The last paragraph of the section *Properties* from the Wikipedia [*Twin prime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#Properties) tell us the elementary sieve that satisfy the sequence of twin primes. I don't know if it, or Brun's theorem, can be useul.

**Computational evidence.** 1) My belief is that the formula $(1)$ provide us many twin prime pairs, but I don't know if it is a remarkable proportion of those. You can evaluate the code (it is a line) using the web Sage Cell Server (choose *GP* as language)

`for(n=1, 100, if(isprime(prime(n+1)+prime(n+2)-1)==1&&isprime(prime(n+1)+prime(n+2)+1)==1,print(prime(n+1)+prime(n+2)-1)))`

And you can do a comparison using this other code

`for(n=1, 881, if(isprime(n)==1&&isprime(n+2)==1,print(n)))`

Previous outputs are thus terms of the sequence *A001359*, from the OEIS. You can to evaluate the code for different segments of integers $1\leq n\leq N$, and choose a different output from the function `print()`

2) My belief is that this sequence/s aren't in the literature.

Comment: We don't know that there are infinitely many twin primes period, let alone twin primes of any particular shape.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer/feedback @StanleyYaoXiao . I am going to wait in next few hours if some user want to provide more feeback. Since if ins't feasible to provide an answer for the question then I should to delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, standard conjectures imply that there should be infinitely many such twin prime pairs even if we insist that $p_{n+1},p_{n+2}$ are themselves twin primes! In other words, there should be infinitely many integers $p$ such that $p$, $p+2$, $p+(p+2)-1=2p+1$, and $p+(p+2)+1=2p+3$ are all prime—this is a special case of Schinzel's Hypothesis H (and almost a special case of the Hardy–Littlewood conjectures prime $k$-tuples conjecture).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.